# knockoutjs optionsCaption for options and select binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have the following markup for my viewmodel:

```
<select data-bind="
    foreach: $parent.Activities,
    value: ActivityId,
    optionsCaption: 'Please select'" 
    class="iaActivities">

    <option data-bind="
            value: Id,
            text: Name,
            attr: { 'title': Name }"></option>
</select>
```

The options are currectly being build based on the items in `$parent.Activities`, also the value is being correctly set as `ActivityId` but **OptionsCaption is not being added and I can't understand why**

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the binding you should use with select :

```
<select data-bind="options: $parent.Activities,
    value: ActivityId,
    optionsCaption: 'Please select',
    optionsText:'Name'"
     class="iaActivities">
</select>
```

[**See fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/dgcSp/)

Comment: @Damien, in the original example, Xgreen is using title attribute and that's probably the reason why he has a foreach binding specified. However in your answer there is no title attribute. The issue here is that when foreach binding is used optionCaption is wiped out. Any ideas?